# Fixed height and scrolleable div

Tags: css

I have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6c8vf5dx/1/) where I want to set a fixed height and set the div scrollable, the height right now is `fit-content`.

[image]

The desired result is to have a fixed height and all inside the box should be scrollable. So only the Start date and End date appear, then if I scroll down inside, it should show the Currently assigned text;

Note: the edit button should follow on scroll, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `.periods-dates` class to the following:

```css
.period-dates {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```